# What does the (absolute) value of the Earth Mover Distance between two histograms mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport

When using the Earth Mover Distance as a metric between two 2D histograms which represent normalized probability distributions, what does the value from the resulting optimization actually mean ?

For example say that I call (in algorithmic notation where $P$ and $Q$ are the two histograms in question):

```
emd(P,Q) = 1.56e-06
```

What does this absolute value actually mean ?

Answer (score 0):

The Earth Mover's Distance is also known as the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric).
The interpretation of the resulting value is a metric that defines you how *similar* two probability distributions (represented by your histograms) are.

Note that this only makes sense if your histograms are actually normed to have a sum of 1, to satisfy the condition on being a probability distribution.

Edit: A graphical introduction to this distance metric is given [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-the-Wasserstein-distance).

Comment: OK. Thank you. But what does the value itself mean - I understand that it is a measure of similarity, but can we say something about the actual value ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of any other interpretation besides the classical one where a earth moving machine moves dirt (the peaks of the histograms) in such a way that the histograms become equal.